# How to change font style and font weight programmatically using c# in metro app for windows 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml

I want to change FontStyle and FontWeight using c# in my code .

I tried this:

```
textblock.FontStyle =FontStyle.Normal
```

and

```
textblock.FontWeight =FontWeight.Bold
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd not recommend to do that in code, but if it is necessary:

```
textblock.FontStyle = Windows.UI.Text.FontStyle.Italic;
textblock.FontWeight = Windows.UI.Text.FontWeights.Bold;
```

Comment: Sounds like that's what the OP tried (though they must have had a using statement for Windows.UI.Text).

Comment: Sure, you are right. The code works, just double checked it. If the using statement is there we need more info/code.

Comment: thanks I was doing this mistake textblock.FontStyle = new Windows.UI.Text.FontStyle.Italic;